# mail function not working

Tags: php, html

I've tried searching for an answer here and on the web and I might be just missing something tiny here.

I got a website hoted (not wamp or anything).
I've written very simple email function to send also an attachment.
for some reason I got no errors and no results.

here is the PHP

```
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $strTo = "my@mail.com";  
        $strSubject = "Purchase request from " . $_POST["formName"] . $_POST["formSurname"];  
        $strMessage = nl2br($_POST["formName"] . $_POST["formEmail"] . $_POST["formInstitute"] . $_POST["formCourse"] . $_POST["formNotes"]);  

        //*** Uniqid Session ***//  
        $strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));  

        $strHeader = "";  
        $strHeader .= "From: ".$_POST["formEmail"]."<".$_POST["formEmail"].">\nReply-To: ".$_POST["formEmail"]."";  

        $strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";  
        $strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";  
        $strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";  

        $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";  
        $strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";  
        $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";  
        $strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";  

        //*** Attachment ***//  
        if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")  
        {  
            $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];  
            $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"])));  
            $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";  
            $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";  
            $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";  
            $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";  
            $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";  
        }  

        $flgSend = mail($strTo,$strSubject,$strMessage,$strHeader);  // @ = No Show Error //  

        if($flgSend)
        {  
            echo "<p>works</p>";  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            echo "<p>not working</p>";  
        }  
    }
    ?>
```

the form is on different page:

```
<form action="#!/studentform.2ndpahse" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
            <table width="500">  
            <tr>  
                <td>שם פרטי: </td>  
                <td><input name="formName" type="text" id="name"></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                <td>שם משפחה: </td>  
                <td><input name="formSurname" type="text" id="surname"></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                <td>דואר אלקטרוני: </td>  
                <td><input name="formEmail" type="text"></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                <td>מוסד אקדמי: </td>  
                <td><input name="formInstitute" type="text"></td>  
            </tr>  
                <td>מסלול: </td>  
                <td><input name="formCourse" type="text"></td>  
            </tr> 
            <tr>  
                <td>הערות</td>  
                <td><textarea name="formNotes" cols="30" rows="4" id="formNotes"></textarea></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                <td>Attachment</td>  
                <td><input name="fileAttach" type="file"></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                <td>&nbsp;</td>  
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="שלח"></td>  
            </tr>  
            </table>  
        </form>
```

Will appriciate any assistance given

Comment: Best guess: Your hoster has disabled it to avoid spammers. This is increasingly common.

Comment: What happens when you call `mail` directly with pre-defined values and no header?  For example `mail('you@email.com','some subject','message body')`

Comment: doesn't send either. but let's say it's the host problem or something, why I dont not get the not sent error? it's just display blank
I tried only mail function and it returned true though.

Comment: My guess would be that PHP is successfully sending the data to the mail server, but the mail server isn't sending it.  You might have to contact your host to get things straightened out.

Comment: From the PHP manual on the mail function: 
Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise. 
It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

Comment: I understand mate, Thank you I'll check it our with my hosting.
file size limit from php.ini is also through host right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a hosting issue eventually and solved by them.